# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'assignmentScores'

Tags: python

I don't understand the meaning of this problem or how to fix it!
I keep getting the problem AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'assignmentScores'
What does this mean? and how do I fix this issue?

My code is:

```
class Student:
    studentName = ""
    studentCourse = ""
    averageMark = 0
    grade = "none"
    assignmentScores = [1, 2, 3, 4]


    def __init__(self, n, c, a, g,m):
      self.studentName = n
      self.studentCourse = c
      self.averageMark = a
      self.grade = g
      self.assignmentScores = m

    def getName(self):
      return self.studentName

    def getCourse(self):
      return self.studentCourse

    def getAverage(self):
      return self.averageMark

    def getGrade(self):
      return self.grade

    def getMarks(self):
      return self.assignmentScores


    def setAverage(self):
      mark = self.averageMark
      return mark

    def setGrade(self):
      grade = self.grade
      return grade

    def setMarks(self):
      marks = self.setMarks()
      return marks

    def addMark(self):
      score = list.append(self, self.assignmentScores)




    def calculateAverage(self):
      if  len(self.assignmentScores) > 0:
        average = sum(self) / float(len(self.assignmentScores))
        return average
      else:
        return 0

    def determineGrade(self):
      return 0

    print(calculateAverage(assignmentScores))
```

Comment: Indentation man , wait let me edit it first

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Oliver. Most pythonistas are nazy about indentation, please fix it.

Comment: `score = list.append(self, self.assignmentScores)` can explain what this statement does?

Comment: Indentation needs to be fixed, where does that class end?

Comment: I think you need to step back, stop looking at the code, figure out what the code is *supposed* to do, and only *then* start writing code.

Comment: You are not creating an instance of Student anywhere so I don't see anything to calculate. trying to `sum(self)` will not be possible. There are so many mistakes as IgnacioVazquez-Abrams has already suggested maybe you should write some pseudocode first to figure out exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will try to solve your problem, but please clear the problem statement ? what do you want to do ? What is input and what do you want in output?

Comment: I want the assignmentScores list to be input into the calculate average function. This will then add up the values within assignmentScores and divide it by the length of assignmentScores (the average of assignment scores) the output will be the calculated average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please use 4 spaces for all indentation, it helps a lot. PEP 8 is your friend and will keep everyone friendly and helpful.

As for your problem, after running the code myself and looking at the traceback, it looks like you assigned the self.assignmentScores list to self itself, so when you type `self.assignmentScores` you are looking up an attribute of self, which is now a list instead of an instance of the class.

This mistake comes from the way you called the method:
`calculateAverage(assignmentScores)`

This method only requires one argument, which is supposed to be an instance of the class Student, but not only are you calling the method directly from the class instead of from an instance, you are using the assignmentScores list as an argument for the method. This makes it so that the method calculateAverage() replaces `self` with `self.assignmentScores` so when you try to check if the list is empty the code is reading it as `self.assignmentScore.assignmentScore` instead of the intended way.

The way you have the class defined at the moment strongly encourages you to call the method like this.

`billy = Student("","",0,"none",[1,2,3,4])
 print(billy.calculateAverage())`

There is another error standing in your way after you solve this problem, but a good look at the traceback and a careful reading of the relevant code will lead you to the solution. Right now all you need is a better understanding of classes and calling methods work.